OpenAI API query for an input document
I could build and chat with openAI model but I wish to upload a document and try to ask questions based on that doc.
I check some discussions like this
My code likes
from langchain_community.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

# load document
loader = CSVLoader("xxx.csv")
documents = loader.load()

# define client
client = AzureChatOpenAI(...)

# use langchain qa
chain = load_qa_chain(llm=client, chain_type="map_reduce")
query = "what columns exist in xxx.csv? list all of them"

response = chain.run(input_documents=documents, question=query)
print(response)

The output will look like it doesn't know anything about the document.
As an AI language model, I appreciate your expertise! What kind of analysis do you want to do, and which data sources do you rely on?

I wonder why that happens and how to fix it? thanks

If we talk about OpenAI, then you should use the Assistants API with the file_search tool. I made a YouTube tutorial on how to build a customer support chatbot that answers questions from the uploaded file. Note, that this tutorial uses the OpenAI Assistants API v1. See the migration guide if you want to use v2. Also, a new tutorial on v2 is coming. Feel free to subscribe to be notified when the new tutorial is out.

Probably the issue is chain_type. I tried with your code, and it wasn't working either. Below code worked:
from langchain_community.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

# load document
loader = CSVLoader("xxx.csv",csv_args={'delimiter':','})
documents = loader.load()
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(deployment_name=AZURE_OPENAI_CHATGPT_DEPLOYMENT, model_name=AZURE_OPENAI_CHATGPT_MODEL)

chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff")
query = "what are the columns listed in the document?"

response = chain.run(input_documents=documents, question=query)
print(response)

Below is the output:

Also, take a look at this: https://github.com/Rohan-Jalil/langchain-chat-with-csv-files/blob/master/main.py
